# How can I hide the UITableView that UISearchBar created?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller, uisearchbardelegate

In my iPhone application I have a search bar and search display controller. When the user types something in the search box, the table view loads and is now visible. When a user clicks on a row, I would like to get rid of the tableView and go back to the view where the user originally clicked the search bar. I have searched all over the documentation, I cannot find how to do this anywhere. I have tried `[tableView setHidden:YES];` but when the user clicks on the search bar again the tableView never returns.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
}
```

Please can someone point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

you can try smth like

> ```
> [mySerchDisplayController setActive:NO animated:YES];
> ```

Comment: I already tried that, it just hides the keyboard, the UITableView is still there.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just remove the table view from the View Hierarchy?

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];

   // update your model based on the current selection

   [tableView removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Comment: Using:

    [tableView removeFromSuperview];
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
    [searchBar setText:nil];

This removes the keyboard and the tableview, but I am left with the Cancel button still there next to the UISearchBar. Thanks for the help so far. Is there no way to remove this cancel button?